# Debian server reboots after every login

Tags: debian, vps, boot, debian-wheezy

I have a Debian Wheezy vps on the cloud.
Today I tried to login using the VNC console provided by my vps service provider but **everytime I login the server automatically reboots after 5 seconds**!
Has anything similar happened to you?
How can you troubleshoot a problem like this in 5 seconds?
Is this the result of a hack or what do you think is causing this?
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: have you tried to log in via ssh? Will it reboot?

Comment: Have tried to login using ssh (text mode)?

Comment: I get connection timed out via ssh, i guess sshd is down

Comment: Does your provider allows you to boot rescue images? (Hetzner did, for example, we're once solved problems such way.)

Comment: @uaaron22 Had the ssh daemon been down, you would get connection refused, not a timeout. Do you have firewall configured on the VM? Does the machine reboot when you logout before 5 sec. have passed?